# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list' Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So im trying to remove some items from a vriable list which i need to use later in the code for a random choice function, but i keep getting this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
def switch():

```
dic = ['a','b','c','1']
global is_on
global dic
def switch():
    if is_on:
        letters.config(bg='red')
        dic = dic - ['a','b','c']
        is_on = False
    else:
        letters.config(bg='green')
        dic = dic + ['a','b','c']
        is_on = True
```

what im trying to do is to remove a, b, c from the list but be able to add it back later.

Comment: it is super important to understand that `global` statements in the global scope **don't do anything** (imo, they should raise an error, but they don't, they are simply not doing anything useful, since the global scope *is global*)

Comment: What makes you think `list` actually supports `-`, i.e. what are you trying to achieve here in the first place? Do you absolutely need a `list` here? There are other datatypes which do support this kind of operation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing elements from lists does not work that way. If you try to subtract a list from list, it will throw an unsupported operand type error. For eg.:

```
>>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print(list - ['a','c'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

You can use numpy to achieve list subtraction. In python 3.9 it looks something like:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print(np.setdiff1d(li, ['a', 'c']).tolist())
['b']
```

Comment: Note that instead of going the roundtrip from list to numpy and back, one can just use the builtin `set` type. That even supports the syntax the OP tried to use.

Comment: I did not we could do this with sets, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

The "TypeError: unsupported operand types for +: 'list' and 'list'" exception in Tkinter typically arises when attempting to concatenate two lists using the '+' operator. To resolve this, ensure that you're using the correct data types and operations for list manipulation in your Tkinter application. You might need to convert the lists to compatible types or use alternative methods like list.extend() or list.append() for concatenation. Review your code and verify that list operations are performed correctly to avoid this error.

Comment: This... doesn't make any sense. The issue isn't related to tkinter and swapping the operator like this leads to an entirely different situation. Please note the [site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).